# Rails: Saving Input whithout Spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, input, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm searching on how to Save my Input without the spaces.

I collect the input on my form via

```
<%= f.input :name %>
```

and use it also for linking

```
localhost:3000/users/:name
```

**The Problem** is, if someone uses Spaces in his name the link is getting all ugly with % signs etc.

How can i store the input without spaces ?

**E.g.**

input is: `Hey im John`
saving as: `HeyimJohn`

My Model:

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

    validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

    # Show Cover
    has_attached_file :cover, styles: { show_cover: "870x150#"}
    validates_attachment :cover,
                                             content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'] },
                                             size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }


    def to_param
        name
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using gsub:

```
> "Hey im John".gsub(/\s+/,"")
 => "HeyimJohn"
```

And to update a hash, you could do:

```
params_hash.each { |k, v| params_hash[k] = v.gsub(/\s+/, "")
```

**Update:**

To update a specific attribute in your model, you could define a setter in the model which removes all the white spaces:

```
def my_attribute=(value)
  write_attribute(:my_attribute, value.gsub(/\s+/,""))
end
```

Comment: I'm Relatively new to Rails. Could you explain me where i have to put the gsub ?

Comment: I was about to get to that, Are you trying to update the parameter hash so that all inputs or selective inputs?  If it's all inputs then doing this in controller after you receive the parameter hash might be quicker, if it's selective then you could do this in the model.

Comment: Only for selective inputs, the :name input. What do i have to include in my model ?

Comment: You could define a setter in your model, `def name=(value) self.name = value.gsub(/\s+/, "") end`

Comment: I'm Getting a "Stack level to deep" Error. I Edited my Question with my Model.

Comment: Oops, try `def name=(value) write_attribute(:name, value.gsub(/\s+/, "")) end

Comment: You're welcome.  I've added an update in my answer to address that as well.